# How to pull samples with a tweedie distribution using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I'm trying to plot a CDF of random samples to compare to a target within a dataset that follows a tweedie distribution.  I know the following code will pull random samples along a poisson distribution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_r = np.random.poisson(lam = coll_df['pure_premium'].mean(), size = len(coll_df['pure_premium'])).sort()

y_r = np.arange(1, len(x)+1)/len(x)

_ = plt.plot(x, y_r, color = 'red')

_ = plt.xlabel('Percent of Pure Premium')

_ = plt.ylabel('ECDF')
```

However, there is no tweedie distribution option on the random sampling. Anyone know how to hack this together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyPI has a [tweedie package](https://pypi.org/project/tweedie/).  A minimal example drawing a sample would be:

```
import tweedie, seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tvs = tweedie.tweedie(mu=10, p=1.5, phi=20).rvs(100000)

sns.distplot(tvs)
plt.show()
```

The package's GitHub pages have a more fancy [example](https://github.com/thequackdaddy/tweedie/blob/v0.0.7/example/tweedie_demo.ipynb).  The package implements [rv_continuous](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html), so one gets a bunch of other functionality besides [`rvs()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs.html).  Also,  while there seems no nice online docs, `help(tweedie.tweedie)` gives lots of detail.

Comment: Thank you @Ulrich Stern.  How would I plot a CDF of what i pull though?  I see there is a CDF methond but it doesn't explain in the docs how to plot it.

Comment: @Jordan, Matplotlib's `hist(cumulative=True)` should work, see [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/histogram_cumulative.html).  Or simply `plt.step(np.sort(tvs), np.arange(1, n+1)/float(n), where='post')` where `n = len(tvs)`.